# Specify file size limit on NTFS share?

Tags: ntfs, share

We have a NTFS file share on a Windows 2k3 server which we'd like to limit file creation size to be a specific size (~1 MB/file or less).  Is it possible to set a limit like this?  If so, how?  I've been unable to find any information related to this specifically.

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in mechanism in any version of Windows Server to do what you're describing. The quota functionality only deals with the total size of files owned by a given user, not with the sizes of indvidual files. The "file screen" functionality in Windows Server 2003 R2 File Server Resource Manager only concerns itself with file extensions, not with sizes.

It would take a fairly low-level hook into the filesystem driver stack in order to implement what you're looking for. I really doubt you're going to find an off-the-shelf utility to do what you're looking for.

You could always run a script that looks for files over that size and deletes them, but that's not going to stop users from saving files there (and potentially thinking that the files are safe and sound).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for your prompt response.

Mark

Comment: FSRM will *report* on files over a certain size, but won't action.  Irritatingly close, but still no cigar.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I can't think of a way to do this.  A couple of quick Google searches didn't bring my any useful answers either.

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I know FTP server software can do this but Windows out of the box cannot do this on shared areas.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be helpful in any way, but a unix samba server could probably support somethig like that via vfs hooks.

If you have an option to move the share to a small bsd/linux box (or put one "in front" of the original server) this might be worth researching.